# Bug with Xcode 5.0.2 - Does Not display simulator with OS options?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5

The deployment target for my app is 6.0.

When I was working with Xcode 5.0 I was able to select the simulator & the corresponding OS version.

Image 1 & 2 display that.

[image: Xcode 5.0 - Image 2]

After downloading Xcode 5.0.2, I am not able to select the OS version of the simulator.

Image 3 & 4 display the same.

[image: X-Code 5.0.2 - Image 4]

Is this a defect or am I missing something?

Comment: If you go to Preferences->Downloads->Components, do you have any of the 5.x or 6.x Simulators installed?

Comment: Yes the simulators are there!

Comment: my components section shows empty area, no 5.x or 6.x simulators to install ??? WTF ???

Answer (score 0):

You probably manually copied the iOS 6.1 SDK into the Xcode 5 package. When you updated, the new version didn't include this, since it's totally unsupported by Apple.

If you want this back, you'll need to copy the SDK into the bundle again. If you don't have a copy still , you can get it by downloading Xcode 4 from the developer center. Keep in mind, this is not approved or recommended.

Comment: Re-installed X-Code 5.0.2, and then copied the 6.1 SDK bundle . But it still does not help.

Still trying ti figure out if this is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Agree on that part Aaron, but the same was working fine for X-Code 5.0

Answer (score 0):

If iOS 6.1 is not listed as an option in the menu, you need to download the legacy simulator in Xcode and then relaunch iOS Simulator.

1. On the menu, choose Xcode > Preferences.
2. In the Preferences window, click Downloads tab.
3. In Components, find the legacy simulator version you want to add, and click the Install button.
4. Relaunch the simulator.